# AJAX Submit Form.. data not sending

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms, upload

> I have been battling with this piece
>   of code for literally days now...
>   Would appreciate any help
>
> The script calls the php file without
>   a problem when the submit key is hit.
>   However, it doesnt post the form data
>   with it.
>
> The HTML form
>
> ```
> <form id="image_form" name="image_form" method="POST"
> ```
>
> action=""
>   enctype="multipart/form-data">
>            File:
>
> The Javascipt
>
> ```
> $(function() {
> $(".submit").click(function() {
>   var obj = document.getElementById("form_div");
>   var load = document.getElementById("load");
>    jQuery.ajax({
>     type: "POST",
>     name: "image",
>     url: "upload_imagel.php",
>     enctype: "multipart/form-data",
>     beforeSend: function(){
>      obj.style.display = 'none';
>      load.innerHTML = "<img src='../images/misc/ajax-loader.gif'
> ```
>
> />";
>           },
>           error: function(){
>            alert('Error has occured');
>           },
>           timeout:5000,
>           success: function( results ){
>            load.style.display = 'none';
>            obj.style.display = 'block';
>           }
>          })
>          return false;
>         });
>       });
>
> The PHP
>
> The following is then empty
>
> ```
> $image=$_FILES['image']['name'];
> ```

---

**Thanks to pekka I changed the following AJAX to**

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var obj = document.getElementById("form_div");
    var load = document.getElementById("load");

    var options = { 
        beforeSend: function(){
             obj.style.display = 'none';
             load.innerHTML = "<img src='../images/misc/ajax-loader.gif' />";
            },
        success: function(){
             load.style.display = 'none';
             obj.style.display = 'block';
            },
        type:      'POST', 
        timeout:   5000 
    }; 

    $('#image_form').submit(function() { 
        $(this).ajaxSubmit(options); 
        return false; 
    }); 
});
```

However still getting the same problem

```
$image=$_FILES['image']['name'];
```

Still empty :(

P.s. html form heading is now

```
<form id="image_form" method="POST" action="sMain/upload_image_small.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to do file uploads using AJAX, because your script will not get read access to a file on the client machine.

You could take a look at the [jQuery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) that uses an invisible iframe to achieve this.

Comment: @Stevanicus strange. Can you show the HTML code of your form?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using Plupload (http://www.plupload.com). It has a lot of features and works well for file uploads.

Answer (score 0):

It does work Pekka, had a typo in my php file. So annoying.

Thanks.. also came across this through a different forum

http://www.ajaxf1.com/tutorial/ajax-file-upload-tutorial.html

Thanks to you both for your help.

Comment: you're welcome. For the future, rather than adding an answer of your own, it's always best to use comments on SO, and updating your question if appropriate (using the "edit" button).